# Default integer'image() width in Ada

Tags: image, integer, width, ada

How can I change the default integer'image() width in Ada?

I'd like to be able to do things like `put("this is a number: " & i'img);` with `i` being for example 5 and having Ada output the number without excess spaces..

Currently I have to do `put("this is a number: "); put(i, 0);`...

Is there any  way around this?

Btw, I know `X'img`is a gnat extension :)

Comment: Similar question answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1846737/cancel-space-after-integerimage-value-in-ada/1847396#1847396

Answer (score 3):

Try something like:

```
Package K is
    Type New_Type is New Integer;
private
  Function Image( Item : In New_Type ) Return String;
End K;

Package Body K is
  Use Ada.Text_IO;

  Function Image( Item : In New_Type ) Return String is
    begin
        Return ("This is a number: " &  Integer'Image(Integer(Item)) );
        -- You could also add a local integer variable, say Integer_Value,
        -- initialized to Integer(Item) and then use Integer_Value'Img.
    end Image;
End K;
```

Comment: what's the `Use Ada.Text_IO;` for?

Comment: Ada.Text_IO is the predefined package for textual input & output functions; it contains Put_Line which is used in the Image function example.

Comment: Oh! LOL -- I used it in testing 'Image... Package K was inside a procedure which declared a variable of K.New_Type; I guess I forgot to remove it after I verified it worked as expected.

Answer (score 2):

The way way you're doing it now provides the most flexibility; using [`'Image`](http://www.adaic.org/resources/add_content/standards/05rm/html/RM-3-5.html) or `'Img` always includes a space for positive values and a "–" for negative values. [§A.10.8 Input-Output for Integer Types](http://www.adaic.org/resources/add_content/standards/05rm/html/RM-A-10-8.html) shows the `Put` procedures available in the generic package `Ada.Text_IO.Integer_IO`. You can instantiate it yourself:

```
package Ada.Integer_Text_IO is new Ada.Text_IO.Integer_IO(Integer);
```

Alternatively, you can use a predefined instance, prescribed by the standard; a renaming may be convenient:

```
with Ada.Integer_Text_IO;
package Int_IO renames Ada.Integer_Text_IO;
```

For convenience, you can define a function that returns `String` and use it with the [`String` concatenation operator, `&`](http://www.adaic.org/resources/add_content/standards/05rm/html/RM-A-1.html).

Comment: @oenone: `'Image` is often seen in the implementation of such packages as `Ada.Calendar.Formatting` and `Ada.Text_IO.Editing`, among others. Can you elaborate?

Answer (score 1):

function Img (X: Integer) return String is
(Ada.Strings.Fixed.Trim (X'Img, Ada.Strings.Both));

Answer (score 0):

Just write your own image function?

```
function Image (X : in Integer) return String is
    Img : constant String := Integer'Image (X);
begin
    if X < 0 then
        return Img;
    else
        return Img (2 .. Img'Length);
    end if;
end Image;
```

then you can just go:

```
put("this is a number: " & Image (i));
```